# Python PyQt - deleting selected table rows, and deletes wrong rows if row isn't selected

Tags: python, indexing, datatable, pyqt5, selected

So I have created a CSV database with PyQT5.The user Has the option to delete last row and selected row

So I have a problem with selecting and deleting selected row:
(I apologize if my problem is hard to understand I don't know how to explain it properly, so here is a small visual representation)

```
1.data1                                                1.data1  
2.data2   -> user selects 2.data2 row and deletes it-> 2.data3   
3.data3                                                3.data4
4.data4

-> but if the user decides to delete last row without selecting the row this is what happens

1.data1                                                                      1.data1
2.data3                                                                      2.data4
3.data4  -> user presses Delete row button, without selecting 3.data4 row ->
-> but the last row doesn't get deleted instead the index of previously selected row gets passed 
and the last selected row gets deleted
```

I have managed to locate the problem somewhere in this block of code, My guess is the problem comes from the .currentIndex(), but I don't know how to set the currentIndex to be None or empty so that it doesn't carry a number.

```
 def deleteSelectedRow(self):
    self.chosenRow = self.table_Database.currentIndex().row()
    print(self.chosenRow)
    if self.chosenRow < 0:
        return
    else:
        self.table_Database.removeRow(self.chosenRow)
```

I had tried setting it to a negative number but that caused the same effect the index of the selected row prevailed the same

Comment: So, in short, the function should delete the selected row, or the last row if none is selected?

Comment: Yes, I have already created a function that deletes last row, however when I tried to implement the option to delete the selected function it stoped working and the last row never got deleted if the user previously deleted a row that he himself selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `currentIndex()` of an item view doesn't indicate a *selected* index: while normally using `setCurrentIndex()` also *selects* the index, you can have a current index even if none is selected.

When an index that was the current is removed from the view, Qt automatically sets (but does *not* select!) the new current to the previous row and/or column depending on what was removed, unless there is no available index (`rowCount()` or `columnCount()` return 0) *or* the deleted index was in the first row or column (in this case, it sets the first available row and/or column).

The simple solution is to check whether there's a *selected* index or not:

```
    def deleteSelectedRow(self):
        if self.table_Database.selectedIndexes():
            row = self.table_Database.currentIndex().row()
        else:
            row = self.table_Database.rowCount() - 1
        if row >= 0:
            self.table_Database.removeRow(row)
```

Considering what explained above, you could also have extended selections which don't show what the "current index" is; if you're supporting selections upon more than one row, you should create a list of rows based on the selected indexes, and remove rows in **reversed** order:

```
    def deleteSelectedRow(self):
        selected = self.table_Database.selectedIndexes()
        if selected:
            # create a set of *unique* rows
            rows = set(i.row() for i in selected)
        else:
            rows = [self.table_Database.rowCount() - 1]
        for row in sorted(rows, reverse=True):
            self.table_Database.removeRow(row)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, I was wondering why it didn't work, you sir have helped me alot